# MS small business server 2003 with exchange 2003 routing issues

Tags: windows-server-2003

I’m running Microsoft small business server 2003 with Exchange 2003. All of our internal mail addresses are setup as FirstNameLastName@server.local . Also; we all have outside mail addresses setup up as FirstInitialLastName@server.com.  There are four of us that have our server.com mail linked to our cell phones and iPad mail so we can monitor while we travel. We would like mail sent to our outside mail address to go to the outside mail address. The issue we are having:  Sending mail to our outside address gets routed back locally by our exchange server. Ex: Sending an email to myself using FirstInitialLastName@server.com  address gets routed back to me locally by exchange.  Is there someplace we can modify this behavior in exchange?

Comment: The `FirstNameLastName@server.local` `FirstInitialLastName@server.com` should point to the same mailbox they are just email aliases of a mailbox. If you send to either you should be able to see them in one mailbox no duality of internal and external boxes.